# How to reset MongoDB Connections?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using M0 Cloud Managed MongoDB. I'm facing with the problem of 500 connections limit. I've checked full of docs to restart the connections but I can't manage to find Restart in Clusters Menu in Cloud Manager. Do I miss something? Any help is highly appreciated. Here is the picture and document I've checked.

https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/tutorial/restart-deployment/
[image]

Comment: I'm running into something similar and would love to know if you figured anything out.  Everything I see says Realm should manage them, but I'm seeing an excessive amount from almost no activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have application(s) that are connected to your deployment that are responsible for these connections. Identify the applications in question, then identify whether they are leaking connections and if so fix them. If your applications genuinely need more than 500 connections you need a higher tier of Atlas.

The document you located is not applicable to you. See [here](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/application/), cloud manager is used when you host MongoDB yourself.

Comment: I used MongoDB Realm. Do you know how to reset or terminate it. I've tried many ways but no luck.

Comment: That I don't know, sorry.